# What Data Structures are available in the Linux Kernel

Tags: data-structures, linux-kernel

Is there a list somewhere of all the major generic data structures used in the Linux Kernel and as a side bonus major places they're used?

What I mean by "generic data structures" is things like doubly linked lists, hash lists, timer wheels, etc.

Also, which ones are considered part of the internally provided api available to modules?

**Edit**

In the `linux/lib` directory I see some promising leads...

```
bitmap.c
plist.c
prio_heap.c
prio_tree.c
radix-tree.c
rbtree.c
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I remember the linux kernel comes with implementations of [Radix Tree](http://lwn.net/Articles/175432/) and [Red-Black Tree](http://lwn.net/Articles/184495/).

Comment: Does it use them for anything?

Answer (score 3):

A relevant LWN article: [Linux kernel design patterns - part 2](http://lwn.net/Articles/336255/)

Answer (score 2):

So, the best way to find out about kernel data structures is via the header files normally found at /usr/include.  A thorough examination of these can be found in in this free on-line resource as well as many other sources:

[Kernel Architecture](http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/)

Two excellent books are:

[Linux Kernel Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470343435)

[Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652)